# Converting multiple rows into one row with multiple columns dynamically, pivot does not seem to work

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm seeing a lot of posts about this but I can't seem to find the right answer.

Here's the data:

[image]

The first 2 rows are part of one set. I want to convert the first two rows into 1 row and have the last column ("Info"), be turned into 2 columns (because there's 2 rows) and because they are different.

Same with the IDs: 14, 24, etc.

This is what I tried:

```
 SELECT 
  BankId,
  BankDate,
  TypeCode,
  Amount,
  FundsType,
  BankRef,
  CustRef,
  Text,
  ptable.Comment1,
  ptable.Comment2,
  ptable.Comment3,
  ptable.Comment4,
  ptable.Comment5,
  ptable.Comment6,
  ptable.Comment7,
  ptable.Comment8,
  ptable.Comment9,
  ptable.Comment10,
  ptable.Comment11,
  ptable.Comment12,
  ptable.Comment13,
  ptable.Comment14,
  ptable.Comment15
FROM (
  SELECT BankId, BankDate, TypeCode, Amount, FundsType, BankRef, CustRef, Text, Info, [16TId], [88TId]
  FROM #test --ORDER BY [16TId], [88TId]
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
  MIN([88TId])
  FOR [Info] IN ([Comment1], [Comment2], [Comment3], [Comment4], [Comment5], [Comment6], [Comment7], [Comment8], [Comment9], [Comment10], [Comment11],
                 [Comment12], [Comment13], [Comment14], [Comment15]
  )
) AS ptable;
```

And this is what the data looks like:

[image]

The data from the "INFO" column does not populate into the "Comment1, Comment2, etc" columns.

I tried to do an PIVOT but it does not work. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: working on it..

Comment: done! please take a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show the `Info` than you should be using `MAX(Info)`. The `cn` is to generate a sequential number for each of the comment / Info

Change to

```
FROM 
(
     SELECT BankId, BankDate, TypeCode, Amount, FundsType, BankRef, CustRef, Text,
            Info, [16TId], 
            cn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BankId, [16TId]
                                        ORDER BY [88TId])
     FROM   #test --ORDER BY [16TId], [88TId]
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX (Info)
    FOR [cn] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
                 [11], [12], [13], [14], [15])
) AS ptable;
```

Comment: thank you so much, my friend. I'll send you some nuts (since you're a squirrel and all :) )